# xpath how to extract the href attribute value based on the content?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

```
<a class="tab-link"> hoho </a>
<a class="tab-link" href="screener.ashx?v=110&amp;s=ta_topgainers&amp;r=41"><b>next</b></a>
<a class="tab-link"> hohaao </a>
```

I'm working on the scrapy
how can I grap the href attribute value based on the content "next" in xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `b` element's text inside this way:

```
//a[b = "next"]/@href
```

Demo from the Scrapy Shell:

```
$ cat index.html
<div>
    <a class="tab-link"> hoho </a>
    <a class="tab-link" href="screener.ashx?v=110&amp;s=ta_topgainers&amp;r=41"><b>next</b></a>
    <a class="tab-link"> hohaao </a>
</div>
$ scrapy shell file:////path/to/index.html 
>>> response.xpath('//a[b = "next"]/@href').extract_first()
u'screener.ashx?v=110&s=ta_topgainers&r=41'
```